# Omit my own activity when using Microsoft Clarity

Tags: wordpress, microsoft-clarity

I have only just started trying out Microsoft Clarity with my Wordpress website.

One thing I have noticed is that it detects and records myself when editing the pages on the site etc.

Is there any way to omit my own user interaction?